# how to add custom class name to rows generated by Jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Here is the code which reads values from database and diplay them in the Jquery DataTable.

This code generate automatic rows and i  want to add some custom classes can any one tell me how to do that

i inspected the Code It Adds

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //jQuery DataTables initialization
        $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
            "processing": true, // for show processing bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process on server side
            "orderMulti": true, // for disable multi column order
            "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">', // for hide default global search box // little confusion? don't worry I explained in the tutorial website
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/Users/GetAllUsers',
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                    {
                        "data": "User_FirstName", "autoWidth": true
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "User_LastName", "autoWidth": true
                    },
                    { "data": "User_IsActive", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "User_Email", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "User_UserName", "autoWidth": true },
                    //{ "data": "User_UserType", "autoWidth": true },
                     {
                         "data": "User_Id",
                         "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            var v_count = full['User_IsActive'];
                             if (!v_count) {
                                 return '<a  class="btn btn-verify " href="#">Enable<i class="fa fa-check wow fadeInRightBig"></i></a>';

                             } else if (v_count) {
                                 return '<a  class="btn btn-verify " href="#">Disable<i class="fa fa-ban  wow fadeInRightBig" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></a>';

                             }
                         }
                     },
                     {
                         "data": "User_Id",
                         "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                             var v_count = full['User_UserType'];
                             if (v_count!=null) {
                                 return '<a class="wow fadeInRightBig"  href="#">' + v_count + '<i class="fa fa-check "></i></a>';

                             } else if (v_count) {
                                 return '<a  class="btn btn-verify " href="#">Disable<i class="fa fa-ban  wow fadeInRightBig" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></a>';

                             }
                         }
                     }



            ]

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/farhadB/4gd62wwu/3/)

```
var dataSet = [['Dadar', 'lmsSenitaD', 'Atul salaskar', '9876543210', '', 'Not Joined', '10/01/2014', '', 'Come back and Join', 'Mobile', 'Times','1'],
    ['Aundh', 'Rashmi', 'Preeti Gupta', '9876543210', '', 'Not Joined', '10/01/2014', '', 'Will Discuss with Family', 'Online Campaign', 'Iksula','2'],
    ['Do@Home_Thane', 'Rashmi', 'Mitali Gupta', '9876543210', '', 'Joined - Old Date', '10/01/2014', '20/08/2014', 'Come back and Join', 'Online Campaign', 'Iksula','4']];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#demo').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');

        $('#example').dataTable({
            "data": dataSet,                
            "columns": [
                            { "title": "Center" },
                            { "title": "Call Executive" },
                            { "title": "Name" },
                            { "title": "Mobile" },
                            { "title": "Phone" },
                            { "title": "Status" },
                            { "title": "Appt Date" },
                            { "title": "Joined Date" },
                            { "title": "Remark" },
                            { "title": "Source" },
                            { "title": "Publisher" },
                            { "title": "css" },
                          ]
                          ,
            "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                var css = aData[aData.length - 1];
                if (css == "1") {
                    $(nRow).addClass('gradeN');
                }
                else if(css == "2") {
                    $(nRow).addClass('gradeC');
                }
                else{
                    $(nRow).addClass('gradeM');
                }

            }
```